# Including .h file breaking down by syntax error

Tags: c

following include instruction will throw out following error:

```
GCC Compiler) ===|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'Length'|
```

I am using Codeblocks. What is wrong in this file(rephrasing: semicolon removed)

```
typedef struct xxxListItem{
    void *data;
    struct xxxListItem *next
}XXXList;
#define XXX_RESULT int
#define XXX_OK 0
#define XXX_MEMORY_ERROR 1
#define XXX_OUT_OF_BOUNDS 2
/*Makros
Keine */

//Prototypen
XXX_RESULT xxx_List_Create(XXXList **pp_list);
XXX_RESULT xxx_List_Insert(XXXList **pp_list, void *p_data);
XXX_RESULT xxx_List_Delete(XXXList **pp_list,int index);
XXX_RESULT xxx_List_Length(XXXList *p_list); //this seems to be faulty!
void xxx_List_Show(XXXList *p_list);
```

Here is main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "XXXList.h"
int main(){
printf("Hello world!\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 4th line `#define XXX_RESULT int;` doesn't need the semicolon `;` at the end.

Comment: Remove semicolon from definition of `XXX_RESULT` ... and go easy with the use of ALLCAPS :)

Comment: Doesn't avoid error(see Rephrasing)

Comment: Error disappeared after having saved file manually. Seems to be bug in Codeblocks.Thx for everybody.

Comment: Would an `enum` be better than a buch of macros?

Comment: There’s a semicolon missing after `next` in the structure.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jonathan Leffler, you are missing a semicolon:

```
typedef struct xxxListItem{
    void *data;
    struct xxxListItem *next; // <--- right here!
}XXXList;
```

Comment: The question is a bit silly.  The original code had the semicolon after `next` but also had `#define XXX_RESULT int;` which made the macro unusable.  Then the code was edited to remove the semicolon after the `XXX_RESULT` macro, but an edit also removed the semicolon after `next`.  As currently written, this is the correct diagnosis.